# Integration test problem using test containers and docker "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: containerId was not specified"

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, testcontainers

I am super new to **testcontainers**. I am not even sure what I am trying to do make any sense or if there is a better approach for it.

Goal: Write an integration test for my MongoDb Repository. I am using Docker, Maven. Jdk11, Spring Boot 2.

My parent test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {PostServiceApplication.class},
        properties = "spring.cloud.config.enabled:true",
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    private static final String MONGO_CONTAINER = "mongo:3.1.5";
    private static final Integer MONGO_PORT = 27017;
    private static final int CONFIG_SERVICE_PORT = 8888;

    @ClassRule
    public static GenericContainer mongo = new GenericContainer(MONGO_CONTAINER).withExposedPorts(MONGO_PORT);

    @ClassRule
    public static DockerComposeContainer configService =
            new DockerComposeContainer(new File("src/test/resources/configservice/docker-compose.yml"))
                    .withExposedService("ConfigService", CONFIG_SERVICE_PORT);


}
```

**ConfigService** is basically the SpringCloud configuration service which is a dependency to the service under the test.

My docker-compse.yaml

```
configservice:
  image: ponte/maven-3.5.4-jdk-11-slim-non-root
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"
  volumes:
    - "~/.m2/repository/app/configservice/configservice/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/configservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:/configservice.jar"
  environment:
    - JAVA_OPTS=""
  hostname: "configservice"
  entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /configservice.jar" ]
```

My test class

```
public class RepoTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoRepo repo;


    @Test
    public void test1() {
        assertNotNull(panoramaPostRepo);

        var post = Post.builder()
                .originalFileName("somefile.jpg")
                .dimension(new Dimension(1200, 480))
                .size(23000L)
                .uploadTime(ZonedDateTime.now())
                .build();


        var savedPost = repo.save(post);
        assertNotNull(savedPost);
        assertNotNull(savedPost.getId());
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed

    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:229)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:207)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.startAmbassadorContainers(DockerComposeContainer.java:249)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.start(DockerComposeContainer.java:159)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer.starting(DockerComposeContainer.java:127)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:29)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.FailureDetectingExternalResource$1.evaluate(FailureDetectingExternalResource.java:30)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:83)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:222)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: containerId was not specified
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:228)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.LogContainerCmdImpl.withContainerId(LogContainerCmdImpl.java:78)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.LogContainerCmdImpl.<init>(LogContainerCmdImpl.java:38)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.logContainerCmd(DockerClientImpl.java:359)
    at org.testcontainers.dockerclient.AuditLoggingDockerClient.logContainerCmd(AuditLoggingDockerClient.java:22)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:285)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:224)
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:76)
    ... 15 more
```

**I also like to know is there any enhancement on what I am doing?**

Comment: I would really recommend using `GenericContainer` here instead of Docker Compose.

Comment: Also, just starting the containers doesn't help - you need to "wire" them to your Spring Boot's configuration. See this example: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/tree/master/examples/spring-boot

Comment: @bsideup Is it possible to use GenericContainer to run my own Jar file on it?

Comment: I have the bootstrap.properties with correct URL of spring cloud in it. The test logs shoes that the URL is getting hit but the service is not available to reponse to it.

Comment: > bootstrap.properties

Is it a static file? If so, this is *not correct*. See https://www.testcontainers.org/features/networking/

Answer (score 1):

In your docker-compose.yaml, you have `configservice`, but later in the code: `.withExposedService("ConfigService", ...)`.

It is case sensitive.

Comment: I fixed it and still the issue exists.